# How to get the browser API calls using Protractor?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, end-to-end

I Need to verify if the required API is been triggered by the browser or not. So, is there a way to get the list of API's that been called by the browser using Protractor?

Comment: What API do you mean?

Comment: when clicked on buttons/navigates to a page in the app, browser makes some Server calls, is there way to get the list of those calls(http requests like post,get etc.,). made by the browser. similar to the retrieving browser logs?

Comment: It's been a while but maybe for someone else it is useful. Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55746616/1306012

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in Protractor or webdriver that I am aware of that will help with this (both of these mostly deal with the front end of the browser, not the server-facing end).  Depending on which browser you are using you may be able to ask it, or install a plugin (E.g., [How do I make the web browser log all activity, including requests, responses, cookie activity, to a log file that I can inspect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706909/how-do-i-make-the-web-browser-log-all-activity-including-requests-responses-c)).

Comment: How about JavaScript?Can we do it using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you want to check if any of REST calls were performed in unit tests. You can use $httpBackend Anguler module for it.