# Verify beacon(https request) on the page using a protractor test

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am writing a protractor test to verify that a request is firing/present on the page load. Is there any way to capture the request by a protractor test?

Manually by monitoring the request calls in network tab (dev tool) it can be seen firing on page load. Looking to automate this case.

On the other hand, I tried locating that link on the page, but since its inside an iframe content(#iframe_id > html > head > script > src= "https..."), it's not accessible(can it be accessed?).

Any suggestion and help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
driver.executeScript(window.performance.getEntriesByType("resource")).then(function (requests) {
   console.log(requests);
})
```

to get an array of all http requests (including xmlhttprequests, css image requests, iframes and etc,) on your page and filter this array as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from @Kirill I created this snipped usable within a protractor "it" test:

```
import { browser } from 'protractor';
import { MyPage } from './pages/myPage.po';

describe('Test my Page', () => 
{
  let page: MyPage;

  beforeAll(() => {
    page = new MyPage();
  });

  it('should display my page and print generated resource traffic', () => {
    page.navigateTo();

    page.clickSomeThingToGenerateResourceCalls();
    page.clickSomeThingelseToGenerateResourceCalls();

    browser.driver.executeScript(function()
    {
      return window.performance.getEntriesByType("resource"); // returns an array of PerformanceResourceTiming objects
    }
    ).then(function (requests)
    {
      console.log(requests);
    });
  });
});
```

---

Documentation links:

[performance.getEntriesByType('resource')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/getEntriesByType)

[PerformanceResourceTiming object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming)

---

In case you want to filter the `requests` you could do so by:

```
browser.driver.executeScript(function()
{
  return window.performance.getEntriesByType("resource"); // returns an array of PerformanceResourceTiming objects
}
).then(function (requests)
{
  for (let index = 0; index < requests.length; index++)
  {
    const element = requests[index];
    if(element.name.indexOf('mydomain') !== -1)
    {
      console.log(element);
    }
  }
});
```